# WSDL/Soap web service response complex array parsing using KSOAP2 library

Tags: php, android, xml, json, nusoap

I have created PHP web service using nusoap

```
$namespace="http:/mynamespace.com/mynamespace"
$server = new soap_server();
$server->debug_flag = false;
$server->configureWSDL("test", $namespace);
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;


$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'Products',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array('ID' => array('name' => 'ID','type' => 'xsd:int'),
        'ProductName' => array('name' => 'ProductName','type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'ImageUrl' => array('name' => 'ImageUrl','type' => 'xsd:string')
        )
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'ProductsArray',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(
    array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:Products[]')
    ),
    'tns:Products'
);
$server->register('GetProductDetails',                    // method name
  array('AgentId' => 'xsd:string'),          // input parameters
  array('return' => 'tns:ProductsArray'),    // output parameters
  $namespace,                         // namespace
  $namespace . '#GetProductDetails',                   // soapaction
  'rpc',                                    // style
  'sequence',                                // use
  'Get Product Details'        // documentation
);

function GetProductDetails($AgentId)
{
    $productArray = array();

    $sqlQry="SELECT pr.products_id, pr.products_image, pd.products_name FROM `products` pr left join products_description pd on pr.products_id=pd.products_id";
    $result=mysql_query($sqlQry);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $product=array();
        $product["ID"]=$row['products_id'];
    $product["ProductName"]=$row['products_name'];
    $product["ImageUrl"]=$row['products_image'];
        $productArray[]=$product;
    }
    return $productArray;
}
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'])?$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

and I am getting response in android something like

```
[Products{ID=29; Name=product1; Url=product1.jpg; }, Products{ID=30; Name=product2; Url=product2.jpg; }]
```

this responce is in one element of `response.getProperty(0)`
and if I paste this code in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ site then it tells me it is not valid json, I am new in nusoap so I don't know how this gives json/XML response
Is there any problem with code?
I have also tried 
Android Code:

```
 SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
 SoapObject nameResult = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(0);
```

In above `nameResult` I am getting all response in one single property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by my self, this is help here if any one needs how to solve this..

I am getting response is parsed using Vector and after that I just simply make a loop that get every attribute and add to `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`.

My process is like, get response from webservice and parsing that response using vector and I just retrieve properties and add to `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`.

So If here anyone wants to parse complexType Array Response and finds problem like me, they can find solution like following code

```
public static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productMapArray = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        request.addProperty("user_id", "1");
   try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Vector<SoapObject> response = (Vector<SoapObject>)envelope.getResponse();
            for (SoapObject soapObject : response) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(KEY_ID, soapObject.getProperty(KEY_ID).toString());
                map.put(KEY_PRODUCT, soapObject.getProperty(KEY_PRODUCT).toString());
                map.put(KEY_IMG, soapObject.getProperty(KEY_IMG).toString());
                productMapArray.add(map);
            }  
            if (response.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("invalid")) {
                result = false;
            } else {
                result = true;
            }

        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            result = false;
            Log.e("Error : ", "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = false;
            Log.e("Error : ", "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used nusoap before but from what I can tell your properly connecting to your db, and according to what i found nusoap can run standard php scripts in which case replaces function GetProductDetails with what i have below (I'm using json_encode), Your problem was with how you load a single result inside the while loop you must use array_push() instead.

```
function GetProductDetails($AgentId)
 {
  // array for JSON response
  $productArray = array();


 $sqlQry="SELECT pr.products_id, pr.products_image, pd.products_name FROM `products` pr      left join products_description pd on pr.products_id=pd.products_id";
  $result=mysql_query($sqlQry);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product=array();
    $product["ID"]=$row['products_id'];
    $product["ProductName"]=$row['products_name'];
    $product["ImageUrl"]=$row['products_image'];
    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($poductArray["products"], $product);
    }
// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($productArray);
}
```

Hope this works it's clearly untested as I dont have your sql (but it's copied from similar script on my server and rewritten for your purposes) also you should cover the case your database is empty

Comment: echo is not working, because it have its own response code as above like ` array('return' => 'tns:ProductsArray'),    // output parameters` and I have also tried with your code return instead of echo but it gives blank array because it is not match to return code.

Comment: okay, i now see this. I am also noticing that function GetProductDetails($AgentId) is returning productArray and in the snippet under $server->register( ...

Comment: There might be something for output response, like to output json or xml. and echo will not work here. it gives '500 server error'. Can you tell me how to parse above response '[Products{ID=29; Name=product1; Url=product1.jpg; }, Products{ID=30; Name=product2; Url=product2.jpg; }]' in android?

Comment: the actual code in short no, unfortunately it would be a fair amount of work to figure out (android has built in functions for parsing json) though it is possible i would recomend figuring out how to properly encode the json try the nusoup forum on sourceforge http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/forums                          if you would like to get a bassis on how this is done refer to http://ec2-54-234-192-222.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Dharmik/json_parser.html (paste this into your eclipse as i just copied my json parser into html doc) the last try-catch block where

Comment: As you gave me link which parse online json but This is response from soap, So i can not make any request directly as you have suggested. I have get one link http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html for parsing such type of array in android, and same response from php tutorial is http://www.discorganized.com/category/php/ . I have tried but still I am missing something..

Comment: okay You are correct i forgot that about SOAP (I'm not very familiar with the protocol) anyways. From what i can tell on seesharpgears link the last function is for the actual parsing in your case you conventiently also have three categories (or name value pairs) what gets returned when you call  this RetrieveFromSoap function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26862/discussion-between-brendan-morrison-and-dharmik)